# Bring to front on Libreoffice extension

Tags: java, eclipse, libreoffice, calc

I want to bring a spread sheet window to Foreground.

If VB, BringToFront or Topmost.

How to do this?

======================================

I found "toFront".

So I wrote below code without conviction, so failed.

"doc" is a instance of XSpreadsheetDocument.

```
    XModel doc_mdl = (XModel) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XModel.class, doc);
    XController cont = doc_mdl.getCurrentController();
    XFrame frame = cont.getFrame();
    
    XTopWindow window = Utils.cast(XTopWindow.class, frame.getContainerWindow());
    window.toFront();
```

Comment: What is `Utils.cast()`? Is it a function you wrote yourself? Have you tried using the ordinary `UnoRuntime.queryInterface()` instead? If that doesn't work, have you tried `frame.getContainerWindow().setFocus()` without casting it to an `XTopWindow`?

Comment: Sorry. "Utils.cast()" do "UnoRuntime.queryInterface()".